# Invalid procedure call or argument in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting this error on command type=0 : Run-time error:'5'. Invalid procedure call or arguement in excel

this image is being shown when 
I try to run the macro while doing automation in exce

[image: imagel]

Comment: Please I really need answer on this quickly.

Comment: Your question will be closed soon unless you edit it to provide more information.

Comment: runtime error when calling excel macro VBA.

Comment: [QueryTable.CommandType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-commandtype-property-excel) cannot be 0. Why do you think it should be? It only can be one of the [XlCmdType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlcmdtype-enumeration-excel).

Comment: Actually , I am new to this VB and I really have no idea why the value of commandType is 0. So, can you suggest me further help!

Comment: I would simply **not** set the `CommandType` at all. Simply remove that code line or put a `'` before it to outcomment it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried this and after that I am not able to run the macro.

Comment: "I am not able to run the macro." What error occurs?

Comment: I mean to say after removing 'CommandType' the macro is not able to execute and getting : Runtime error: '1004' "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: Cannot reproducing. What I wrote in my answer is tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least `Excel 2016` puts this code line `.CommandType = 0` in the code while recording a macro while getting a QueryTable. But it is definitely wrong and fails while running that recorded macro later. So do removing it.

Instead the recorded:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "...", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "..."
...
```

use:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "...", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    ' .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "..."
...
```

Hint: Recording a macro is a good start. But knowledge about the used objects according to their documentation is also necessary. So always have a look at this documentations. In this case [QueryTable.CommandType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-commandtype-property-excel) .